# Plotting adjusted survival curve for a mixed-effects cox regression and/or time interaction?

Tags: r, mixed-models, survival-analysis, cox-regression, survival

I have created a mixed effects cox regression using coxme.

**Q1)** I would like to plot the coefficients of the fixed effects in an adjusted survival curve. However, it seems this functionality in packages like `survminer` is only possible for coxph objects without a frailty term.

**Is there anyway that this could be calculated and plotted manually in R instead?**

I have the below model for demonstration purposes:

```
library(survival)
library(coxme)
kidney <-  data.frame(kidney)

coxme <- coxme(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + (1|disease), 
                  data = kidney)
```

**Q2) Additionally, is there anyway that this could be plotted for a time interaction (`tt()` in `coxph`)?**

For instance with the model:

```
library(survival)
kidney <-  data.frame(kidney)

coxph.me <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + tt(sex) + frailty(disease), 
                  data = kidney,
                  tt=function(x,t,...) x*t)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This post seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149986/survfit-equivalent-for-coxme-in-r

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most popular way to obtain adjusted survival curves from a model is g-computation, which requires a function to make predictions for survival probabilities at *t* given a vector of covariates and *t*. Unfortunately, the `coxme` function does not naturally support such predictions, e.g. there is no `predict.coxme` function included in the package.

You can, however, use the `adjustedCurves` package in conjunction with the `riskRegression` package to get what you want if you switch from `coxme` to a standard `coxph` model with a `frailty()` term. Below I give an example on how this could be done. It is a little hacky because of a bug in `riskRegression` but it works just fine.

```
library(riskRegression)
library(adjustedCurves)
library(survival)

set.seed(42)

# simulate some example data
sim_dat <- sim_confounded_surv(n=500, max_t=1.2)
sim_dat$group <- as.factor(sim_dat$group)
sim_dat$cluster <- sample(1:10, size=nrow(sim_dat), replace=TRUE)

# outcome model
# NOTE: your frailty term needs to be named "cluster" due to some
#       sub-optimal coding in the riskRegression package
cox_mod <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ x1 + x2 + x4 + x5 + group + 
                   frailty(cluster),
                 data=sim_dat, x=TRUE)

predict_fun <- function(...) {
  1 - predictRisk(...)
}

# using direct adjustment 
adjsurv <- adjustedsurv(data=sim_dat,
                        variable="group",
                        ev_time="time",
                        event="event",
                        method="direct",
                        outcome_model=cox_mod,
                        predict_fun=predict_fun)

plot(adjsurv)
```

[image: surv]

If you need confidence intervals as well, you can obtain those using bootstrapping by changing the code a little bit (note that this may take a while, especially if you have lots of data).

```
# using direct adjustment with bootstrap confidence intervals
adjsurv <- adjustedsurv(data=sim_dat,
                        variable="group",
                        ev_time="time",
                        event="event",
                        method="direct",
                        bootstrap=TRUE,
                        n_boot=500,
                        outcome_model=cox_mod,
                        predict_fun=predict_fun)

plot(adjsurv, conf_int=TRUE, use_boot=TRUE)
```

[image: surv_ci]

None of this works with a `tt()` term in the model formula though.

Comment: Thanks Denzo. This seems to have worked in an R script and is outputting a plot, but is throwing up errors in rMarkdown.

`Quitting from lines 864-881 [ac_REC] (cox_regression_writeup.Rmd)
Error in `check_inputs_adjustedsurv()`:
! The 'event' variable has to be a binary event indicator. For data with competing risks, see the 'adjustedcif' function.
Backtrace:
 1. adjustedCurves::adjustedsurv(...)
 2. adjustedCurves:::check_inputs_adjustedsurv(...)`

These errors are strange as my event variable is binary (1,0). 

Do you know a solution for this?

Comment: If you can construct a small reproducible example of this error I am happy to take a look at it but otherwise I can't really help here. If you have one, you can submit is as an issue here and I will try to help: https://github.com/RobinDenz1/adjustedCurves/issues

Comment: Hi Denzo, I am considering reporting the survival probabilities from your solution. I just wanted to double check how this method is accounting for the frailty term in the survival curve, given that it is exploiting a bug?

Comment: It is not exploiting a bug, it works despite the bug (which will be fixed in the upcoming CRAN release of riskRegression because I reported it). For details on how the survival curves are estimated I recommend: https://doi.org/10.1002/sim.9681 (G-Formula method).
To check how the conditional survival probability estimates are created from the cox model you can take a look at the source code of the predictRisk.coxph.penal function of the riskRegression package