# Adding patients at risk to adjusted Kaplan Meier curves and changing the color of the curves in r

Tags: r, colors, survival-analysis, adjustment

I am trying to do adjusted Kaplan Meier curves based on the variable named `group`.
How do I add **patients at risk** to adjusted Kaplan Meier curves and how do  I change the color of the curves?

Here is my code and simulation data obtained after reviewing this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77654561/plotting-adjusted-survival-curve-for-a-mixed-effects-cox-regression-and-or-time)

```
library(riskRegression); library(adjustedCurves);library(survival)
set.seed(42)
sim_dat <- sim_confounded_surv(n=500, max_t=1.2)
sim_dat$group <- as.factor(sim_dat$group)
sim_dat$cluster <- sample(1:5, size=nrow(sim_dat), replace=TRUE)

cox_mod <- coxph(Surv(time, event) ~ x1 + x2 + x4 + x5 + group + cluster,  data=sim_dat, x=TRUE)

predict_fun <- function(...) {
  1 - predictRisk(...)
}

# using direct adjustment 
adjsurv <- adjustedsurv(data=sim_dat,
                        variable="group",
                        ev_time="time",
                        event="event",
                        method="direct",
                        outcome_model=cox_mod,
                        predict_fun=predict_fun)

plot(adjsurv, custom_colors = c(  "red","blue") )
```

I read that there are many other packages in `R` but none reported patients at risk.

**EDITS**

I found a relevant [link](https://robindenz1.github.io/adjustedCurves/reference/plot.adjustedsurv.html) from which I could change the color of curves (added in the code above) but I wasn't able to add a`at-risk patinets` although they suggested using `cowplot::plot_grid`.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The *survminer* package reports numbers at risk below the curves.

Comment: @Edward Thanks for your reply. Please let me know how to combine both (plot from prior code) and patients at risk from `survminer` in 1 figure. Appreciate your input.

Comment: I found a relevant [link](https://robindenz1.github.io/adjustedCurves/reference/plot.adjustedsurv.html) from which I could change color of curves but wasn't able to add a`at-risk patinets` although they suggested using `cowplot::plot_grid`.

Comment: @Denzo Please let me know your precious thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You are in luck! I have recently pushed an update to the package that allows adding risk tables to the plot. All you need to do is to install the developmental version from github (`install_github("RobinDenz1/adjustedCurves")`) and you will be able to do it simply by using:

```
plot(adjsurv, custom_colors=c("red", "blue"), risk_table=TRUE)
```

Since you are using `method="direct"`, I would recommend keeping `risk_table_stratify=FALSE`, because the output may otherwise be confusing (see documentation page of `plot.adjustedsurv()`).